# How to create wsdl soap request using nodejs soap

Tags: node.js, xml, soap, wsdl

I used node.js soap to send a soap request, but I am keeping getting the error.

In SoapUI my xml looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:acl="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Acl.WcfService.Model">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GetOrder>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:args>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <acl:ApiKey></acl:ApiKey>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <acl:OrderId></acl:OrderId>
         </tem:args>
      </tem:GetOrder>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is my code:

```
var args = {
    'args': {
        'ApiKey' : '***',
        'OrderId' : '***'
    }
};

soap.createClient(wsdlURL, function (err, soapClient) {

    soapClient.GetOrder(args, function (err, result) {
        //the result goes here
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }

        console.log(result);

    });
});
```

Here is the error:

a:InternalServiceFault
Bad Api Key

Please someone help me on this?

Comment: Forgot to mention that the ApiKey I'm using is working on SoapUI.

Answer (score 1):

I have made it work using strong-soap.

Here is the code:

```
"use strict";

var soap = require('strong-soap').soap;
var url = 'http://acldev.azurewebsites.net/CmsService.svc?singleWsdl';
var requestArgs = {
    args: {
        ApiKey : '***',
        OrderId : '***'
    }
};
var options = {};
soap.createClient(url, options, function(err, client) {
    var method = client['CmsService']['BasicHttpBinding_ICmsService']['GetOrder'];
    method(requestArgs, function(err, result, envelope, soapHeader) {
    //response envelope
        console.log('Response Envelope: \n' + envelope);
    //'result' is the response body
        console.log('Result: \n' + JSON.stringify(result));
    });
});
```

(This is the return of client.describe():

```
{ CmsService:
{ BasicHttpBinding_ICmsService: 
{ GetOrders: [Object], GetOrder: [Object] },
 BasicHttpBinding_ICmsService1: { GetOrders: [Object], GetOrder: [Object] } } }
```

)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to use a namespace for your apiKey and orderId. You need to see in your soapclient sdk how to setup namespaces

Comment: According to doc on github [link](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#clientmethodargs-callback---call-method-on-the-soap-service) I tried to add the namespace prefixes to the element names acl:ApiKey, acl:OrderId and tem:args. It will throw me an error said "acl/tem is not recognized".....